# Finding Programs in the Primes

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, primes, printable-ascii

Let's assign the numbers 0 through 94 to the 95 [printable ASCII characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters):

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Space is 0, `!` is 1, and so on until `~` is 94. We'll also assign 95 to tab (`\t`) and 96 to newline (`\n`).

Now consider the infinite string whose Nth character is the character above that the Nth [prime number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), modulo 97, has been assigned to. We'll call this string S.

For example, the first prime number is 2, and 2 mod 97 is 2, and 2 is assigned to `"`, so the first character of S is `"`. Similarly, the 30th prime number is 113, and 113 mod 97 is 16, and 16 is assigned to `0`, so the 30th character of S is `0`.

The first 1000 characters of S are as follows:

```
"#%'+-137=?EIKOU[]cgiosy $&*,0>BHJTV\bflrt~
#%1=ACGMOY_ekmswy"046:HNXZ^dlrx|!)-5?AKMSW]eiko{"&.28DFX^hntv|%+139?CEQ[]agmo{  $,6>HPV\`hnrz~+5ACMOSU_mqsw$(*.BFNX`djp~!'-5;GKQS]_eoq{}"48:>DJRX^tv
'17=EQU[aciu    026<>DHJNZ\b#)/7ISaegkqy}   $0:<@BFLXdlx~!'/3;?MQWY]ceku(.24LPR\hjt|!'-?EIKWamu$28<>BDNZ`fxz)+AGOUY[_gmwy"0:@LNRT^jl|~#')3;Meiow&(,4DFJRX^bnp%+-37=KQUW]agsy    ,06BJPTn
)15;=CYegw  ".<FHLTZ`dfjpx|~#-/9AES]ikquw&48>FLPbjtz
'1=KOU[]y{$,0>BJV\hlr%/1A[_amsw"(04<RTXZf!#)/59?AMQ]_ik{},2FV^bdhj
'39CEIOQWacoy{$28<BJPVfrtx%+/7AIOUkqs}*.4FHR`dfp~!);?EGKQS_cw,8:>DJLRhjp
%139EUW[aosu&>HNPZ\fhrxz#%/5=[egqy  (:@LXZlrv|!35?MSWY]uw"(8@FL^nptz|!'17COacim &>BDHNP\`n+5;GU[eqsw}$*46:HNTX^`jl|'/AEKWY_ek&,:>FPXdvz|
7CIK[agu    ,0NTZ`hnrt
%)+1GMOSegkwy   "<BHLT^~-/59;?AKY_cku{.24:X\dntz!'37=?EIOQ[]ms&*6D`fz~/7=AGU[akmw"*46@HT^vx|#)-5GQW]_eo{}&,28@FPVX^djt|39OQcgoy6>PTV`fhnr#+7IY_ams} (*0:HLdfvx!#-AEGKScioq},48>\^hjptz
'-1=CKW[iu  6<HNPfn
)/=ACIS[aek(6@BNXZjl~5GM]ouw(,24>FPV\dhnpz|'+179EIWims&*28<DHV\`nz~
=AY_eq}*046:LR^
```

Stack Exchange turns tabs into spaces, so [here's a PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/UsnUU0Dz) with the tabs intact.

## Challenge

Find a [substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) of S that is a valid program in your language of choice that outputs the first M prime numbers, **one per line, in order**, for some positive integer M.

For example, `2` is a substring of S (it occurs in multiple places but any will do), and `2` is a valid [CJam](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) program whose output is

```
2
```

which is the first M = 1 prime numbers, one per line, in order.

Similarly, the string `2N3N5` may be a substring of S somewhere, and `2N3N5` is a valid CJam program that outputs

```
2
3
5
```

which is the first M = 3 prime numbers, one per line, in order.

### Scoring

The submission with the highest M wins. Tie breaker goes to the submission posted first.

### Details

- There should be no additional output besides the single primes on each line, except for an optional trailing newline after the last line. There is no input.
- The substring may be any length as long as it's finite.
- The substring may occur anywhere within S. (And S may contain it in multiple places.)
- The program must be a full-fledged program. You may not assume it is run in a REPL environment.
- The program must run and terminate in a finite amount of time without errors.
- "Newline" may be interpreted as any [common newline representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) necessary for your system/interpreter/etc. Just treat it as one character.

You must give the index of S where your substring starts, as well as the length of the substring if not the substring itself. You may not only show that the substring must exist.

<sup>*Related: [Looking for programs in a huge Boggle board](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44607/26997)*</sup>

Comment: Can you give the code to produce that big string upto any number of characters ? (I suppose you already have one)

Comment: If there are 95 printable ASCII characters then why are you doing modulo 97? Ah nevermind, you also use tab and newline.

Comment: Considering that 0 mod 97 can only occur once, the lack of space really hurts...

Comment: @Sp3000 Shoot, that didn't occur to me. :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), M = ∞

All of the programs start at the beginning of the string. The following poorly written Python program calculates how many characters are needed for a given M.

```
def program_length(n):
    PLUS, MINUS, DOT = '000', '001', '100'
    i = 1
    s = ''
    while n > 0:
        i += 1
        if all(i%f for f in range(2,i)): 
            s += str(i) + '\n'
            n -= 1
    out = '110111'
    ch = 0
    for c in s:
        dif = ord(c) - ch
        if dif > 0: out += PLUS * dif
        else: out += MINUS * -dif
        out += DOT
        ch = ord(c)
    return int(out, 2)
```

For example, for M = 5, the program is the first 2458595061728800486379873255763299470031450306332287344758771914371767127738856987726323081746207100511846413417615836995266879023298634729597739072625027450872641123623948113460334798483696686473335593598924642330139401455349473945729379748942060643508071340354553446024108199659348217846094898762753583206697609445347611002385321978831186831089882700897165873209445730704069057276108988230177356 characters.

Comment: If in doubt, there's a BF variant that'll do it for you.

Comment: It's funny how Lenguage was inspired by another challenge of mine. It's like I'm bringing about my own downfall.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, M = 2

Short and sweet:

```
2NZ
```

This sequence starts at position 54398, using 1-indexing of the string.  You can test it online [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2NZ).

I attempted to search for a few possible variations, but this was the first solution I found.

I am currently trying to find an M = 3 version, but I don't expect to find one within a reasonable period of time.  If the sequence is uniformly random (an approximation), then the starting index for a length 5 sequence could be on the order of 10^9.

Comment: Verified: `1e6{mp},97f%' f+"2NZ"#` [link](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1e6%7Bmp%7D%2C97f%25'%20f%2B%222NZ%22%23) (takes a while :p)